# Get Database field names in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to get the database field names as shown in the example below.  I just need to retrieve the name and not the value.

[image]

This is as how far I got where `rptDoc` is my `reportDocument` and report has been loaded.

```
private void getFieldNames()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= rptDoc.Database.Tables.Count; i++)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Check if it exists: rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].Columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working as follows;

```
private string getCommandNames()
        {
            StringBuilder commandNamesFound = new StringBuilder();
            String delimiter = Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in rptDoc.Database.Tables)
            {
                commandNamesFound.Append(table.Name);
                commandNamesFound.Append(delimiter);
            }

            return commandNamesFound.ToString();
        }
```